# SWT Transparent pixels changed to white

Tags: java, image, swt

I'm trying to create a transparent image and then draw another image onto it that contains transparent/translucent pixels. After the image is added translucent pixels are set to white in comparison to being being a mixture of the colour and alpha. This is causing there to be a white outline around the image.

The image has to be shown on a ToolBar as a ToolItem with transparent pixels.

Is it possible to draw an image with transparency without it changing the transparent pixels to white?

*Overlay Image*

[image: Overlay Image]

*Processed Image*

[image: Processed Image]

```
final Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setSize(285,305);

// Create a transparent image
final Image transparentImage = new Image(null, 256, 256);
final ImageData imageData = transparentImage.getImageData();
imageData.transparentPixel = imageData.getPixel(0, 0);
transparentImage.dispose();

// Create an image with the transparent data
final Image processedImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(),
        imageData);

// Get the image to draw onto the transparent image
final Image overlayImage = new Image(display, "overlay_image.png");

final GC imageGC = new GC(processedImage);

imageGC.setAntialias(SWT.ON);

imageGC.drawImage(overlayImage, 0, 0);

imageGC.dispose();

// Create the components and add the image
final ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.BORDER);

final ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
item.setImage(processedImage);

toolBar.pack();
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}

overlayImage.dispose();
display.dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the image you used, it has a transparent color white, so if you want to use that image, or you change transparent color manipulating the image with a program (GIMP?), or you can give the same transparent color to both the images, so first take the transparent color from the image "overlay_image.png"  at position (0,0) and only alter set the same transparent color for the second (transparent) image. this is the working code with your image:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem;

public class TestTransparency {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(285,305);


        final Image overlayImage = new Image(display, "overlay_image.png");
        final ImageData imageDataOverlay = overlayImage.getImageData();
        imageDataOverlay.transparentPixel = imageDataOverlay.transparentPixel;


        // Create a transparent image
        final Image transparentImage = new Image(display, 800, 600);
        final ImageData imageData = transparentImage.getImageData();
        imageData.transparentPixel = imageDataOverlay.transparentPixel;
        transparentImage.dispose();
        final Image processedImage = new Image(Display.getCurrent(),
                imageData);



        final Image overlayImage2 = new Image(Display.getCurrent(),
                imageDataOverlay);
        final GC imageGC = new GC(processedImage);
        imageGC.setAntialias(SWT.ON);
        imageGC.drawImage(overlayImage2, 0, 0);
        imageGC.dispose();

        // Create the components and add the image
        final ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(shell, SWT.FLAT | SWT.BORDER);
        toolBar.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
        final ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.NONE);
        item.setImage(processedImage);

        toolBar.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
        }

        overlayImage.dispose();
        display.dispose();



    }

}
```

Please note that, using GIMP manipulating your image:

[image]

or using a good transparent image like this: http://www.stickpng.com/img/icons-logos-emojis/tech-companies/youtube-play-logo your code works fine!